# Scrolling on overflow when making a list of N items

Tags: css

I have a `prompt-box` div that has a `max-height` of 80% of the screen.

Inside of it, I have a `ul` which holds a bunch of `li` elements depending on how many the user adds.

How do I configure this so that once that `prompt-box` hits a certain size, new items can be added to the list but the contents just scroll instead of overflowing like this?

Thanks!

[image]

**Edit: Adding html & css**

```
        <div className='prompt-box'>
            <p className='title'>What's in your future?</p>

            <ul className='options-holder'>
                {
                    this.state.items.map(item => (
                        <li key={item.id} className='option'>
                            <div className='circle' />

                            <p className='item-text'>{ item.text }</p>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }

                <li key={0} className='option form'>
                    <div className='circle' />

                    <form className='new-item-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <input className='new-item-input' placeholder='Type something and press return...' onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.text} />
                    </form>
                </li> 
            </ul>

            <button className='confirm-button'>Continue</button>
        </div>

.prompt-box {
    @include absolute-center;

    background: #1E1E1E;
    width: 35%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    color: #ccc;
    font-family: 'Circular Book';
    max-height: 80%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.prompt-box .title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.prompt-box .options-holder {
    list-style: none;
    border-radius: 3px; // not currently working
    padding: 0;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 12px auto;
}

.prompt-box .option {
    background: #303030;
    padding: 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.1); 
}

.prompt-box .option.form {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.prompt-box .item-text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 18px;
}

.prompt-box .new-item-form .new-item-input {
    background: transparent;
    border-style: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    color: white;
    width: 80%;

    &:focus { outline: none; }
}

.prompt-box .confirm-button {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 22px auto 18px auto;
}
```

Comment: This what overflow: auto is for :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us any HTML/CSS code for us to reproduce and test a fix for the issue, but adding something like this should work, to allow that container to scroll vertically when its height is exceeded:

`.prompt-box {
  overflow-y: auto;
}`

Comment: Thanks Jon. I just added it

Answer (score 0):

Try a `overflow: scroll;` style rule on your div.prompt-box.  (You're already giving it a max height, so the extra contents should have a vertical scroll bar).

Comment: This is true and it works. What I'm going for is: 1) the `prompt-box` should expand until it hits its max-height and then just the grey part should scroll, not the whole parent (which is `prompt-box`)

Comment: Oh, then put the overflow rule on the <ul> tag instead.

Comment: Thanks Karl. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I threw a `max-height` and an `overflow-y: scroll` on the `ul` and it did the trick.